# How to display the photo without lossing quality

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, camera, photolibrary

Hi i am new to the iOS.

I wish to implement photo editing functionality in my app. that photo will be retrieve from **iPhone photo library**. I tried to place the photo in UIImageView. but i did not get better result. UIImageview does not show the photo as its being in photo album. there is lots of resolution and quality is missing.

If i want to show photo with original resolution and quality as its being in photo album. what are steps i need to follow. if any one knows please guide me right way.

```
    editingPhotoContainerIMV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [editingPhotoContainerIMV setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

Comment: If you just pick and add image to `UIImageView` then there's no reason if quality of image degrade. Are you sure you are not applying any image manipulation like resizing or any other stuff before you add image to `UIImageView`?

Comment: Yes. i did not apply any image manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is you are on a Retina device, when you load your UIImage, you should be using:

```
UIImage *photoImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)imageRef scale:2 orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
```

EDIT: Assuming the problem IS with Retina devices, then you need to get a CGImageRef. If you already have the UIImage, then you can replace 'imageRef' above with 'myUIimage.CGImage'. If not, if he image is in a file, then you can use UIImage's initWithContentsOfFile - look at the UIImage class reference. The key is to get the CGImage out of the UIImage, then get a new image with a scale factor of 2. The only way iOS lets you do that is with the method I showed up top.

Comment: Thanks for your response David, In (CGImageRef)imageRef what i have to add. please advice me

Answer (score 0):

Try ALAssetRepresentation [fullResolutionImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html)